# What does an asterisk mean in function signature in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am encountering `sum_` function :

```
    def sum_(cols: Column*) = cols.reduce(_ + _) / 60
```

What does `*` mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a variadic function, the `*` means the argument is a varargs (variable length argument)

It means it can receive from 1 to n Columns as argument.

You can call the function as `sum_(colum1, column2) or sum_(colum1)` or with any number of column as argument.

You can also store your values in a List and send them to the function with the proper syntax:

```
val list = List(column1, column2, column3)
sum_(list: _*)
```

It seems that it will return the result of adding all the values of the columns received divided by 60

You can find more info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-varargs/)